# javafx textbox colors

Tags: colors, textbox, javafx

Hey I was wondering if it was possible to have different colors in a text box in javafx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the CSS style. Look at the [CSS Reference Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/javafx/javafx/1.3/docs/api/javafx.scene/doc-files/cssref.html).